# How to sort by odd lines then remove repeated values?

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have the following type of file:

```
transcr_25793 +
YAL039C -
transcr_25793 +
YAL037C-B -
transcr_20649 +
YBL100C -
transcr_7135 +
YBL029C-A -
transcr_11317 +
YBL067C -
transcr_25793 +
YAL038W +
transcr_7135 +
YBL029W +
```

I was trying to get something like this:

```
transcr_7135 +
YBL029C-A -
transcr_7135 +
YBL029W +
transcr_11317 +
YBL067C -
transcr_20649 +
YBL100C -
transcr_25793 +
YAL039C -
transcr_25793 +
YAL037C-B -
transcr_25793 +
YAL038W +
```

Then, afterward, I was looking for something like this:

```
transcr_7135 +
YBL029C-A -
YBL029W +
transcr_11317 +
YBL067C -
transcr_20649 +
YBL100C -
transcr_25793 +
YAL039C -
YAL037C-B -
YAL038W +
```

I've scrolled through `sort` manual and some posts, but couldn't find anything that fit near this, just `sort` using numerical values to get odd lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly the sorting order you've showed, but maby right as well?

```
$ cat input.txt|paste - -| sort -k1,1V -k2,2| tr "\t" "\n" | awk '{if($0 in line == 0) {line[$0]; print}}'
    transcr_7135 +
    YBL029C-A -
    YBL029W +
    transcr_11317 +
    YBL067C -
    transcr_20649 +
    YBL100C -
    transcr_25793 +
    YAL037C-B -
    YAL038W +
    YAL039C -
```

EDIT:

Insert the line number and uses it as a sorting key, should produce the exact output you like:

```
$ cat input.txt | paste - - | nl | sort -k2,2V -k1,1g | cut -f2- | tr "\t" "\n" | awk '{if($0 in line == 0) {line[$0]; print}}'
```

Comment: It doesn't show exactly the way I posted, but for my case it doesn't matter, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Pure `gawk` solution:

```
awk -F_ 'NR%2{i=$2;next}{a[i]=a[i]"\n"$0}
         END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";
             for(i in a) printf "%s","transcr_"i""a[i]"\n"}' file
```

The trick is to sort indexes of array `a` numerically with a little help of `gawk`'s PROCINFO special array.

```
transcr_7135
YBL029C-A -
YBL029W +
transcr_11317
YBL067C -
transcr_20649
YBL100C -
transcr_25793
YAL039C -
YAL037C-B -
YAL038W +
```

BTW, its a pity awk doesn't offer an option to sort naturally a.k.a. *version sort* (according to text with numbers).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `sort` and assuming the lines don't contain TAB characters:

```
paste - - < file | sort -V | tr '\t' '\n' | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

Or `sort -t$'\t' -sk1,1V` to preserve the original order for entries with identical odd lines like in your expected output.

If you don't have GNU `sort`, and assuming the odd lines always follow that pattern, you can replace `sort -V` with `sort -k1.9n`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for element in $(sed -n 'p;n' a.txt |sort -nk 1.9 |uniq |awk '{print $1}')
do
    echo $element; cat a.txt |grep -A1 $i |grep -v trans |grep -v \\\\--
done
```

Where a.txt is your input. Tested:

```
[root@megatron ~]# cat a.txt
transcr_25793 +
YAL039C -
transcr_25793 +
YAL037C-B -
transcr_20649 +
YBL100C -
transcr_7135 +
YBL029C-A -
transcr_11317 +
YBL067C -
transcr_25793 +
YAL038W +
transcr_7135 +
YBL029W +
[root@megatron ~]# for i in $(sed -n 'p;n' a.txt |sort -nk 1.9 |uniq |awk '{print $1}')
do
echo $i; cat a.txt |grep -A1 $i |grep -v trans |grep -v \\\\--
done
transcr_7135
YBL029C-A -
YBL029W +
transcr_11317
YBL067C -
transcr_20649
YBL100C -
transcr_25793
YAL039C -
YAL037C-B -
YAL038W +
[root@megatron ~]#
```

Comment: It appeared this `transcr_45
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
transcr_193
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
transcr_231
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
transcr_282
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.` and so on... Do you know what I can do?

Comment: I corrected. You have to use |grep -v \\--    . Or just try to re-use the updated code.

Comment: Even when exactly copying your solution and even the file with the same name, it doesn't work out... It keeps showing the same error

Comment: You can download it from here: wget http://54.38.222.163/sort.sh and run it with sh sort.sh . The text must be in a.txt

Answer (score 0):

Pre- and postprocessing with `awk`; this does not assume that a `transcr` line is followed by just one `Y*` line; it's also idempotent -- its output could be piped back as input and it will give the same result.

```
awk '{print $0~/^transcr/ ? t=$0 : t" "$0}' /tmp/foo | sort -t_ -k2n -k2 -u | awk '{print (NF > 2) ? $3" "$4 : $0}'
transcr_7135 +
YBL029C-A -
YBL029W +
transcr_11317 +
YBL067C -
transcr_20649 +
YBL100C -
transcr_25793 +
YAL037C-B -
YAL038W +
YAL039C -
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to restate you problem. You really want to do two operations:

- Sort the odd-numbered (`transcr*`) lines by the number in the line, keeping the even-numbered (`Y*`) lines associated with the previous line
- Merge all of the `Y*` lines that fall under identical `transcr*` lines

While I admire the single-line solutions in the other answers, I think that this is complex enough that writing a script may be justified. Plus, once you store the script in a file, you can reuse it and enhance it as your needs change.

This script will take your input and produce lines identical to your final output:

```
#!/bin/env python

from collections import defaultdict
import fileinput
import re

def pair_lines (iterable):
    ''' Return lines two at a time '''
    args = [iterable] * 2;
    return zip(*args)

dd = defaultdict(list)
for line1,line2 in pair_lines(fileinput.input()):
    # accumulate lists of all second lines that share the same first
    # line value
    dd[line1].append(line2)

def line_index (line):
    ''' Return first substring that looks like an integer '''
    return int(re.search(r'\d+',line).group(0))

# sort by first lines and print results
for line1 in sorted(dd.keys(), key=line_index):
    print(line1, *dd[line1], end='', sep='')
```

Run with:

```
reorder.py input.txt > output.txt
```